# Перераспределение памяти в C++

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, memory-management

*Есть старый прибор, с ним - старый компьютер. Можно было писать программы для управления прибором на C и паскале. Внезапно приехала поддержка, установила глобальное обновление: результат - писать можно только на C++ (старые программы на C почти все работают, правда, выдаётся куча предупреждений). Это была лирика.*

Памяти у прибора мало. В C-ных программках для прибора использовали `malloc()` и, когда необходимо, `realloc()` - иначе новые структуры могли просто не влезть. Теперь можем оперировать классами - плюс. Минус - совсем плохо с памятью.

**Вопрос:** теперь, когда можно (и нужно) использовать C++ с его оператором `new`, как лучше перераспределять память?

Сразу отвечу: какой компилятор - не известно. Прибор лишь выдает, что в нём отныне используется стандарт C++ от 2002 года. Более того, компилятор - не на компьютере, а в приборе; компьютер, фактически, - лишь придаток управления.

В чём минус продолжения использования старых программ на C: раньше, после инициализации прибора и запуска программы, под данные было доступно 1680 мибибайтов. Теперь, если запускать **ту же программу на C** - 1120 мибибайтов (не хватает для обработки образца). А если на C++ по новому (со стандартным классом ввода-вывода) - остается 1720 мибибайтов, но в процессе работы куча фрагментируется так, что происходит остановка прибора с ошибкой "Heap memory needs to be defragmented".

Российская техподдержка помочь не может :( Западная (производитель прибора) заявляет, что прибор вышел из зоны срока эксплуатации и, если читать между строк, "мы вообще должны быть благодарны, что о нас не забыли, а кинули косточку, и даже с кусочком мяса" :(.

Comment: Ну, malloc и realloc никто из C++ не выкидывал, можно продолжать использовать С++ как "улучшенный С". Посмотреть только, чтоб старый софт не использовал чего-то, что в С и С++ по-разному работает. Но неужели при наличии компилятора С++ нет компилятора С? что-то прямо слабо верится...

Comment: @Harry C-ный код выполняется, я, видимо, некорректно выразился, сейчас исправлю. Но наличие классов позволило бы  улучшить работу с прибором в плане удобства, например, снимать показатели в процессе работы, а не только после её окончания.

Comment: В целом на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) есть описание тех же `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, да, перед вами новые возможности, но, будьте готовы, что для того чтобы получить это самое удобство, вам необходимо бОльшую часть программы писать с нуля. Если написано было не много - вам повезло. Если программа была готова, и вот сейчас вы хотите что то улучшить... ИМХО, вы выбираете очень мучительный и долгий труд)

Comment: @test123 Мы готовы :) Прибор в чём-то уникален (не в плане возможности исследования, а в плане его дешевизны). 75% программ вообще были написаны на паскале :)

Comment: Касательно вопроса, Страуструп [советует](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#renew) использовать для этих целей контейнеры C++. Скорее всего, вам подойдет `std::vector`, если раньше функционал был на C.

Comment: :O доступно полтора гига? Это, по вашему, мало памяти? Я то думал там обычные 16-64КиБ... Тогда вы можете писать как для полноценного ПК.

Comment: @test123 Увы, мало. Геном человека = 3.2 Гб. Понятно, что нам не нужны все данные из него, плюс, мы используем все ухищрения, чтобы снизить затраты памяти (полубайтовое кодирование), но эффективное использование прибора = данные от 1000 человек и более.

Comment: @test123 А вообще, в биоинформатике сейчас меньше 32 Гб свободной памяти - признак чрезвычайной бедности :) И пока на смену NGS не придут более совершенные методы - так и будет :(

Comment: Откровенно говоря, раз у вас такой дефицит памяти - вряд ли применение С++ вместо С что-то вам даст. Imho, конечно. Но, может, использовать какой-то свой менеджер памяти, который бы как-то учитывал конкретные особенности прибора/расчетов?.. пожалуй, это единственное, что остается. Ну и - поменьше всяких перераспределений памяти в программе. Иногда уж лучше malloc сделать побольше, чем потом дыры при перераспределении оставлять.

Comment: А на этом "приборе" какая-то уникальная архитектура и операционная система, что приходится пользоваться каким-то архаичным встроенным компилятором сомнительного качества?

Comment: Если стоит проблема фрагментации памяти, то может помочь ручное управление распределением памяти (арены) и placement new.

Comment: Ох ... как я молотом пришиб :) Если что, я хотел лишь предложить возможный дубликат. Но может и такой вариант будет подходящим.

Comment: @VTT Примерно. Этот прибор позволяет сделать анализ соматических мутаций для 10-15 человек примерно за 17 тысяч рублей. Да, современные приборы позволяют сделать аналогичный анализ сразу для 200 человек и за немного меньшие деньги. НО! Сколько вы будет собирать анализы для 200 человек, когда для десятка вы собираете недели за три (предположим, что вы всё хорошо законсервировали, и у вас ничего не протухнет, а за последнее я не поручусь)?  Какова вероятность ошибки баркода (система разделения анализов разных пациентов) для 10-15 человек и для 200? - 0.04 и 0.33

Comment: @free_ze Где бы побольше почитать о ручном распределении памяти? Всё - вижу ссылку на дубликат. Ушёл читать.

Comment: Я имел ввиду не уникальный функционал этого прибора, а аппаратную платформу и операционную систему. Какой там у вас процессор и ОС? Может под них есть более толковые компиляторы с возможностью кросс-компиляции?

Comment: @VTT Компьютер, возможно, мы можем подключить любой - это всего лишь интерфейс. Что касается прибора, это почти черный ящик. Процессор, вроде бы, PowerPC. Система, скорее всего, *nix based. Это всё, пожалуй. Как я понимаю, мы вообще одни из немногих клиентов, кто пытается на лету программировать. Остальные тупо ждут результатов и уже потом делают анализ, а это потери (ладно бы во времени, но часто и в том, что приходится делать доп. анализ)

Comment: Это у Вас Roche Junior?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Roche+Agilent+Dell. На Junior похож, но не он.